# How can I sort values in a column based on the unique value in other column (i.e. its group)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my DataFrame I want to sort X per group_id in descending order.

```
           X         group_id    y
0        2.660535        1     3180
1       -1.076041        1     5543
2        9.331677        1    14142
3        5.989031        1    22393
4        1.548646        1    24194
5        2.687961        1    28181
6       -3.105952        1    34263

...           ...      ...      ...
```

Comment: do you want the rest of the dataframe with it?

Comment: is `df.sort_values(['group_id', 'X'])` what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, but I also want descending order for X and ascending for group_id. So I want to group by group_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
df.sort_values(['group_id', 'X'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I should've read the docs for `ascending` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) might help you out.

You might try something like `df.sort_values('group_id', ascending=False, inplace=True)`

or…

`asc = df.sort_values('group_id', ascending=True, inplace=False)`

`desc = df.sort_values('X', ascending=False, inplace=False)`